# Multiple Policy for snowflake tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake support multiple row access policies on a table.

Say I have 3 policies A, B, C and I want to enforce these policies on a single table T.

Answer (score 0):

No, at this point we can have 1 RAP per table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.
Srinath is right we only have one Row Access Policy per table, you can apply multiple masking policies on a table not sure if that serves your purpose. If it does do check out https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-masking-policy.html

Comment: Can we have a policy with no parameters. i.e no common field between security table and actual data table.(My policy will be evaluated based certain user level info only)

Comment: create or replace row access policy rap_it as (empl_id varchar) returns boolean ->
  case
      when 'it_admin' = current_role() then true
      else false
  end
;      why is empl_id needed can we skip it

Comment: No, the parameter cannot be without parameters since that is the column value which will be used for evaluation of RAP which needs to be applied during the SQL Execution.

Comment: Unfortunately no, that 'parameter' is the signature for the row access policy and is the mandate one not optional.

Comment: Consider this, you have a table with cars with registraion_no and owner_name column. you want two roles one to view odd reg no. and another to view even reg no. So, you have to use the registration_no. column as the signature in the policy definition.